# How to control an embedded device without static IP over internet in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, networking, embedded

We have a device without static IP, connected to internet, we want to send data to the device to control it and need to receive report data from device periodically by server application in rails. What are the possible way to accomplish this using http and ruby?

Is there a way to do this without dyndns?

Comment: Does the devise expose an HTTP server? Can it do dyndns?

Comment: Do you also write the software for the device, or just the server?

Comment: is there any other way than dyndns?

Comment: we write server side only, but in position to suggest the device firmware developers possible methods of communication.

Answer (score 1):

Its more a server / routing question. Has not much to do with ruby on rails it self. If your devise supports dyndns then your problem is solvable.

- 1 Tell the devise that you are usign dyndns
- 2 Register your dyndns domain here for example: http://dyn.com/dns/
- 3 The devise will always update the dyndns domain with the new ip
- 4 Set the virtual host configuration for your server like this:

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>   ServerName my.dyndns.domain
>   DocumentRoot ...
>   ...
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

And now the devise should be reachable for others or your rails application.

Comment: the scenario we use the devices, is like internet of things(IOT) concept, they are in large quantity, so registering and maintaining dyndns names would be big task. It would be better if it can be done in any other way, may be http tunneling? or something?

Answer (score 0):

You could have the device phone home when it comes up. If you have a server out on the public internet, the device could know how to contact the server and register itself for updates.

If the device knows to poll for updates via HTTP or some other protocol, that also gets you around firewalls and NATs in many cases.